# Check if validator with param is applied to form control

Tags: angular, validation

In an Angular application, I am using Reactive Forms to build a form and passing some validators.
I am using a Field class.

I want to check, in the class constructor, if a specific validator is in the list of validators. I can do this when the validator take no arguments, but I don't know how to check when they do.

// Initialise Field class from a component

```
this.field = new Field({
    validators: [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(20)
    ]
});
```

// Constructor of field class

```
export class Field {
    constructor(data) {
        hasRequired = false;
        hasMax = false;
        for (let i = 0; i < data.validators.length; i++) {
            // This works
            if (data.validators[i] === Validators.required) {
                hasRequired = true;
            }
            // This doesn't, as Validators.maxLength takes in an argument
            if (data.validators[i] === Validators.maxLength) {
                hasMax = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation you can look at it

Comment: I had read the documentation, it doesn't solve my problem.